# Scala creating functional objects using implicit parameters

Tags: scala, implicit

How can I pass implicit parameters when creating functional objects in trait?

This code cannot be compiled.

```
case class Cache(key: Int, value: String)

trait Processor {
  val process = processF _ // error: could not find implicit value for parameter cache: Cache

  private def processF()(implicit cache: Cache): String = cache.value
}

object Main extends App with Processor {
  implicit val cache = Cache(10, "hello")

  process()
}
```

I expect to do something like this:

```
val process: ()(implicit cache: Cache) => String = processF _ // syntax error
```

Or are there any available approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike methods, function objects can't have implicit parameters.

I think

```
// in Processor
def process(implicit cache: Cache) = () => processF()

// in Main
process.apply()
// or
val process1 = process
process1()
```

is the closest to what you want. Alternately,

```
trait Processor {
  implicit val cache: Cache

  val process = processF _ // error: could not find implicit value for parameter cache: Cache

  private def processF(): String = cache.value
}
```

Comment: Thanks, both ways helped me :)